# Could not verift ST Device!. Remote GDB Server

Tags: debugging, gdb, stm32, raspberry-pi3, openocd

I'm trying to debug my st device(STM32F401CCU6) remotely. I'm using raspberry pi 3 for debugger. I had install openocd on RPI. I set everything up in STM32CUBEIDE 1.8.0.

When I debug my code appears this message box. I search a while. I did configure "stm32f4xx.cfg" file for device ID.

[RPI3 ready to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLE4k.png)
[STM32CUBEIDE 1.8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgGfL.png)

Comment: In STM cube you need to use GDB debugging for that (not standard STM32 C/C++ Application)

Comment: I'm using GDB debugging in STM32CUBEIDE 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve with downgrade from STM32CUBEIDE v1.8.0 to v1.6.0. I can flash program and debug. But there is one more issue. I want to use live expressions when debugging. But it doesn't work like this.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I knew it works with 1.6.0. But, why does it not work with higher versions? Any idea or solution?